# Overide 'del' keyword python

Tags: python

Me and a friend are coding a game using pygame in python, I was wondering if there was a way to override the `del` keyword in python, similar to how you can override operators (such as += with `__iadd__`, for example).

I have a kill() function for my sprite but we wondered if we could override the del statement to do something similar (just because it would be a really cool use of sytax)

I've tried the `__del__` and `__delete__` functions but either I do not understand what these methods are for or they are not run when `del` is run.

Is there any way to provide a custom method to be run when `del` is executed?

ex.

```py
class Example:
    def some_magical_function(self) -> None:
        # Other code to delete the object
        print("Object deleted!")

test = Example()
del test
>> Object deleted!
```

Thank you!
PS. My first post so sorry if there are any formatting errors or anything :P

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question earlier?

Comment: @Barmar Earlier than an hour ago? This is the same question you commented on back then.

Comment: If this is the same question, where are my comments?

Comment: All five comments by you and someone else rather looked like answering, so I flagged them accordingly.

Comment: why is this question a duplicate? i was asking if you can override the __del__ method, the question i have been marked as duplicating is about __del__, which i have already read.

Comment: @Trevor If you really want to know, you might want to notify the closer about your comment (with @ like I just did).